# Typescript Error: TS2339: Property 'span' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

All of a sudden my react typescript project has started rejecting `<span>` tags with

```
TS2339: Property <span> does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'
```

Every other tag is absolutely fine, but `<span>`s any where in my `.tsx` files throw this error.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Can anyone advise?

- Make sure you have `import * as React from 'react'` in your file
- Update types for react `npm install @types/react`

Comment: I cleared and "npm install"-ed my packages and everything sorted itself out so marked this answer as closest.

Answer (score 38):

I had the same problem but for me, it was the `p` element.
The reason for the error was that I refactored a `p` element to `h3` for instance and VSCode changed also the type definition.

As you pointed out cleaning the node_modules and doing a fresh `npm install` does the trick.

Just wanted to point out what could cause the problem.

Comment: Did you report a defect against VSCode?  Seems bogus for it to modify files under the node modules directory.

Comment: To be honest. I didn't. Not thought about that this could be a bug.

Comment: Thanks. I had this exact same problem. Refactored (renamed) an element via F2 in VSCode and it renamed the type definition for div within `interface IntrinsicElements` in node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts.

Comment: Yep, same issue for me... found out the hard way that using rename in JSX tag names seems to rename every single instance of that HTML tag, throughout your entire project, and even affects node_modules too as we've discovered.

Comment: Hmm I've used F2 to rename HTML elements before and it only affected that one instance. All of a sudden this time it decided to do it globally

Comment: Simply `npm uninstall @types/react` and `npm install @types/react` is fine too, for me there was no need to remove the entirety of node_modules. Takes a long time for some people to delete it heh

Comment: npm i @types/react@latest did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue with section element.
literally, what worked for me was:
deleting the type declaration - JSX.Element, and the  element, and return them.
after that VSCode accepted.